# SpookyJS: Console.log Doesn't Work Inside Then

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

```
try {
  var Spooky = require("spooky");
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

var spooky = new Spooky({
  capser: {
    logLevel: "debug",
    verbose: true
  },
  child: {
    command: "./casperjs/bin/casperjs",
    port: 8081,
    spooky_lib: "./node_modules/spooky/"
  }
}, function (err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  spooky.start("http://www.google.com");
  spooky.then(function () {
    console.log("7331");
    this.emit("printmsg", "1337");
  });
  spooky.run();
});

spooky.on("printmsg", function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
});

spooky.on("error", function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

When run, `1337` will be displayed, but `7331` will not. Why is this? The reason I'm asking is because it makes it difficult to debug when you want to log the values of certain variables.

Also, if you want to change the then function like so:

```
spooky.then(function () {
  var self = this;
  this.evaluate(function () {
    self.emit("printmsg", "Hello World!");
  });
});
```

This won't work because `evaluate` doesn't have access to the self variable. In PhantomJS you can make it `page.evaluate(function (self) {` but that isn't working when I try it with Spooky. So it's very difficult to log data when you want to.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This could have been caught earlier, if there wasn't a typo: `capser` should be `casper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found what was causing me this problem since posting this question, so I will share the answer below, in case anyone else encounters a similar problem:

In the standard quickstart example on [the SpookyJS Github page](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS), there's a commented-out 'console' event listener in Spooky which, when uncommented, will cause all output from Casper to appear on the screen:

```
// Uncomment this block to see all of the things Casper has to say.
// There are a lot.
// He has opinions.
spooky.on('console', function (line) {
    console.log(line);
});
```

When this event listener is set, it will log all output from Casper to the screen. The examples I was trying to log to the console in my question were all being run inside calls that Spooky was passing to Casper to process, so that's why I was not seeing them displayed. With this event listener set, my output appears, as well as the output used by the `__utils__.echo` function call in xShirase's answer.

Additionally, Casper provides an `echo` function which can be used to send output outside of Casper's evaluate function, which, by default, only has access to the scope of the page being viewed:

```
spooky.then(function () {
  this.echo("foo");
});
```

Since the standard configuration sets Casper's logging level to `debug` and sets verbose logging on, a lot of information will be displayed once this event listener is set. This can be avoided by setting the logging level to `error` or some other [logging level supported by Casper](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/logging.html).

Answer (score 1):

Oh how I stuggled with that one!
At first, i was basically doing :

```
var msg = this.evaluate(function () {
    return('1337');
  });
console.log(msg);
```

Then I discovered that Casper injects a really useful clientutils module to each page : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html

It enables you to send logs from the remote DOM like so :

```
casper.then(function () {
this.evaluate(function () {
    __utils__.echo('1337');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you sure this works with Spooky, though?

    `spooky.start("http://www.google.com");
      spooky.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function () {
          __utils__.echo("1337!");
        });
      });`

That still isn't printing anything when I run it.

Comment: Spooky creates a Casper instance, so yes, it should definitely work

Comment: hmm well it's not working. But it looks like the Spooky github (which I should have checked first, but didn't) is saying to call the emit function and then have evaluate return something as an argument to that, interestingly enough. Thanks for your answer though, definitely gives me some help on using Casper in the future.